# About java final access modifier

Tags: java

I am making Java Swing application. i made check box item, then when i was calling `show.isSelected()` method, i got an error that you have to make show final, then i made it final and the error was gone, the error was in the 9th line, but i did not understand that what was the reason for making show final and what final does with show ?

```
    final JCheckBoxMenuItem show=new JCheckBoxMenuItem("Show");
    show.setSelected(true);
    show.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) 
        {

            formpanel.setVisible(show.isSelected()); ////// giving error without final

        }

    });
```

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class

Comment: This error shows you're using an old version of Java. Java 8 automatically detects if references are effectively final.

Comment: If you use Java 8, you don't have to explicitly declare it `final`. Effectively final is enough, i.e. you don't reassign the variable anywhere.

Comment: Try using a search engine the next time ...

Comment: Assuming you're not using Java 8? If so, why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `final` keyword prevents you from reassigning reference `show` so the compiler can safely copy its value into new anonymous object created by `new ActionListener` statement.

Comment: could you please give me an example ??